# CKEditor, how to change AJAX Get for Post when uploading image?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, get

I am using CKEDITOR.
I want to upload image on localhost by AJAX. 
When uploading image, CKEDITOR send some parameters by GET like that

```
http://localhost/adminUploadImage?CKEditor=editor1&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=ru
```

I am using MVC and here my routes:

```
'admin/menu/([0-9]+)' => 'admin/menu/$1',
'admin/deleteMenu/([0-9]+)' => 'admin/deleteMenu/$1',
'admin/insertMenu' => 'admin/insertMenu',
'admin/uploadImage' => 'admin/uploadImage',
```

So I can't get parameters of GET, because route don't understand this URL

```
class 'AdminController' does not have a method 'actionUploadImage?CKEditor=editor1&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=ru'
```

How can I change GET to POST? or you can help to find another solution...